# Split string by character that is in front of another character

Tags: java, regex, split

i want to split a string: "value.value2.key: somethink.two"
and i want to get elements in array:

1. "value"
2. "value2"
3. "key: somethink.two"

So i need regex for it. Split by `"\\."` before characters and `":"`
Thanks for help.

Comment: What did you try? Why did it fail? What other use-cases have you tried and which ones are failing? Why do you need regex? Where is your code? What happened when you debugged your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead assertion.

```
String s = "value.value2.key: somethink.two";
String parts[] = s.split("\\.(?=.*?:)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

`(?=...)` called positive lookahead assertion. `(?=.*?:)` positive lookahead asserts that the match must be followed by `.*?`, zero or more characters and a colon symbol. So it matches all the dots before the colon but not the one after the colon , since the last dot is not followed by colon.

**Output:**

```
[value, value2, key: somethink.two]
```

Comment: From me too an upvote. It works. Perhaps the down voter did so out of jealousy. :)

Comment: Many thanks. You just know how to write that? I had problem with "(?=.*?:)"

Comment: I just don't know what meaning has "=" in regex.

Comment: @Patrik Staron This might help: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html